# How can I make rake tasks run in an environment other than dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a staging machine with a special "staging" environment. I always forget to run rake tasks on that machine like:

```
rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=staging
```

So instead I end up doing:

```
rake jobs:work
```

And then I'm mystified why nothing has changed in my database. Doh! It's because I didn't remember to supply RAILS_ENV=staging.

But I will never, ever need to run anything as the development environment on that server. How can I make rake tasks run in the "staging" environment by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a line that sets the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` in a file that will get run when you log onto the machine.  For example, I'm a bash user, so I'd put the line

```
export RAILS_ENV=staging
```

In either ~/.bashrc (just for me) or /etc/bashrc (for everyone who logs onto the machine).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

```
Rails.env = 'staging'
```

Put this in your task file.