# Rails: Make this rake task aware that it is in the test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, environment, seed

I have the following rake task defined in my `lib/tasks` folder:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare => :environment do
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Now, what this does is seed the test DB when I run `rake db:test:prepare`. I do this because I have some basic records that must exist in order for the app to function, so they're not optional and can't really be mocked.

Separately, I have a model that uses S3 for asset storage in development and production, but I don't want it to use S3 for testing. I have set up a method in the model that changes the storage path from S3 to local if `Rails.env.test?`

However, this isn't working. I was wondering if the rake task was aware of what environment it was being called from, and it turns out it is NOT. I put this at the top of my seeds.rb file:

```
puts "Environment Check: Rails Environment = #{Rails.env}"
```

Sure enough, when the task runs this prints: `Environment Check: Rails Environment = development`

So, how can I redo this rake task so that when it's seeding the test DB it knows that it's seeding the test DB??

Comment: That would be really odd if `Rails.env` isn't giving you the correct value. Look elsewhere (how/what you're calling ).

Comment: Honestly, nothing else. I type `rake db:test:prepare` into the console, and when it hits the seed task it puts `environment=development`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having this problem too; in my `db/seeds.rb` file I have a block that creates user accounts in the development environment, but they were also being created when preparing the test environment to run `rake` for RSpec or Cucumber testing, which resulted in a wall of red.

**Updated**: I've found that the [best way to specify the environment for rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492463/how-can-i-make-rake-tasks-run-in-an-environment-other-than-dev/5492695#5492695) is to specify the environment within the task, above all statements that need the environment to be set. So in this case:

```
Rails.env = 'test'
Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
```

does the job.

Comment: This is great -- much better than remembering to set the environment in the command line each time. Thanks!

Comment: That was what drove me to try my original method--I couldn't stand having to put `RAILS_ENV=test` before every `rake` command. Setting the environment as an argument to `invoke` works if you only have the one task to run, but setting it at the start of the preparation block works best.

Comment: Note that merely setting the Rails environment prior to invoking the task is not sufficient to load fixtures from environment-specific folders.  This is because seed_fu initializes the fixture paths when rake is first loaded prior to `Rails.env = 'test'`.  To overcome, add a line after `Rails.env = 'test'` that says: `ENV["FIXTURE_PATH"] = Rails.root.join('db/fixtures').to_s`. This will cause seed_fu to recalculate the fixture paths using the `test` environment rather than the `development` environment under which you first execute the rake command.

Comment: The above comment also applies when using [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank). Then you'd probably want to invoke `db:seed:test` as `db:seed` would run your development seeds.

Answer (score 8):

From reading the [db:test tasks's source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake), it looks like they only care about grabbing the test db info from database.yml, but don't care which actual environment they're doing it under.

You might need to run rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test to ensure you're under the test environment.