# How to seed test data in Rails not using seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, minitest, rake-task

I have `seeds.rb` populating my development database. And I know I can easily apply `seeds.rb` to my test database using:

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

However, I want a ***different*** `seeds.rb` file to populate my test database. Maybe `seeds_test.rb`. This must be an extremely common requirement among rails programmers, isn't it?

If there's no easy way to do this, like `rake db:seed:seeds_test RAILS_ENV=test`, then how would I create a rake task? I would think something like this in `lib/tasks/test_seeds.rake`:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Seed data for tests"
  task :seed_test => :environment do
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds_test.rb"
  end
end
```

I think that'll work, but then I would love for my rake task to automatically know to apply this only to the test database without me having to specify:

```
rake db:seed_test RAILS_ENV=test
```

How do I get the rake task so all I have to enter in the command line is:

```
rake db:seed_test
```

***UPDATE***: Another stackoverflow question was linked to where the answer was to do this:

```
Rails.env = 'test'
```

Unfortunately that doesn't actually do anything (at least as of Rails 4.2) :(.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Make this rake task aware that it is in the test environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525757/rails-make-this-rake-task-aware-that-it-is-in-the-test-environment)

Comment: Unfortunately that answer to that duplicate question (which is not really a duplicate) doesn't work :(. `Rails.env = 'test'` doesn't actually change the environment and the seed data goes into the development database.

Comment: Doesn't it? I just tested it, and it definitely works for me (data added to `test.sqlite3` only). (I copied your code, put `Rails.env = 'test'` just above `load`.) I also run Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: Loading test data is an extremely common requirement. The most common approach is to use fixtures for test data. Why not use fixtures and `rake db:fixtures:load`?

Comment: @Amadan - I enthusiastically tried this `Rails.env = 'test'`, but it loaded the data to the `development.sqlite3` database only, not the `test.sqlite3` database. Leading me to question what purpose the `Rails.env = 'test'` statement had. @blowmage, fixtures seems to make sense, I just keep reading how fixtures should never be used...

Comment: @at. have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872271/adding-a-custom-seed-file ?

Comment: @BasiaMadej - that's not my issue. I want to force the rake task to use the test database or test environment.

Answer (score 12):

In `db/seeds.rb`, test for the value of `Rails.env` and execute the respective seeding:

```
#db/seeds.rb
case Rails.env
when 'development'
  # development-specific seeds ...
  # (anything you need to interactively play around with in the rails console)

when 'test'
  # test-specific seeds ...
  # (Consider having your tests set up the data they need
  # themselves instead of seeding it here!)

when 'production'
  # production seeds (if any) ...

end

# common seeds ...
# (data your application needs in all environments)
```

If you want to use separate files, just `require` them inside this structure, e.g.:

```
#db/seeds.rb
case Rails.env
when 'development'
  require 'seeds_development'    
when 'test'
  require 'seeds_test'
when 'production'
  require 'seeds_production'
end

require 'seeds_common'
```

or shorter

```
#db/seeds.rb
require "seeds_#{Rails.env}"
require 'seeds_common'
```

Comment: This isn't my issue. I want to always write to my test database.

Comment: Oh, I thought defining a custom `rake` task to write test-specific seeds to your test database was only what you were looking to do _if there was no easy way_ to have `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test` write test-specific seeds to your test database.

Comment: You need to use double quotes for string interpolation:

`require "seeds_#{Rails.env}"`

Comment: @VictorHugoBueno thanks for the heads-up. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `spring`, you can [set a Rails environment for a rake task](https://github.com/rails/spring#rake):

```
# config/spring.rb
Spring::Commands::Rake.environment_matchers['db:seed_test'] = "test"
```

or for all tasks matching a regex pattern:

```
# config/spring.rb
Spring::Commands::Rake.environment_matchers[/^db:.+_test$/] = "test"
```

This allows you to call

```sh
rake db:seed_test
```

and have it run in the `test` Rails environment, thus writing to your `test` DB.

**However**, this doesn't have any effect

- if `spring` isn't used for rake
  or
- if the rake task isn't invoked directly (e.g. from the command line) but as a dependency of another rake task not matching the pattern

Comment: This looks very interesting, will try it tomorrow