# Cron + Rake task trying to invoke sqlite3 (only Dev/Test) in Staging (rake works from shell)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, cron, rake, environment

In my Rails 3.2 app I have a custom rake task that I am trying to run every day at 5pm with a cron job. Right now I am running it on our site's Staging server. The cron job is setup correctly but according to the e-mail output from the cron daemon the rake is being aborted because it's trying to invoke sqlite3.

Here is my cron job:

```
#crontab
0 17 * * * cd /u/apps/my_app/current && /usr/local/bin/rake my_task
```

I have reserved sqlite3 for development and test, like so:

```
#Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'                
  gem 'letter_opener'                      
  gem 'rspec-rails'            
  gem 'sqlite3'                             
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pry-rails'                              
end
```

I also have set my rake task to load the proper environment like so:

```
#mytask.rake
task :my_task => :environment do
    # my task
end
```

This is the error I'm getting in the e-mail from crond:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

If I run the rake tasks directly from the shell I don't get an error. It would seem that this works because of the following line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias rake='RAILS_ENV=staging rake'
```

This, however, doesn't seem to have any effect on the task when run from the cron job. I've tried adding `export RAILS_ENV=staging` to the `.bashrc` file as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492463/how-can-i-make-rake-tasks-run-in-an-environment-other-than-dev/5492695#5492695) but it didn't help.

The one thing I've found that works is writing the cron job like this:

```
#crontab 
0 17 * * * cd /u/apps/my_app/current && /usr/local/bin/rake my_task RAILS_ENV=staging
```

...with the env declaration directly in the cron command. This doesn't seem very elegant but it's okay for now. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: how about `0 17 * * * cd /u/apps/my_app/current && export RAILS_ENV=stage /usr/local/bin/rake my_task`?

Comment: My current solution is the same, just with the env declaration at the end of the second command of the cron job. I was hoping to find a way to set it up so I don't need to declare it for every cron job task.

Comment: Is `sqlite3` available on your staging part in your Gemfile?

If you run `RAILS_ENV=staging rake my_task` does it succeed? (I think not).  

Also, are you sure that you have limited SQLite for dev and test only? Are your config files set up for that?

Comment: @xlembouras If I run the rake tasks directly from the shell I don't get an error. Adding "RAILS_ENV=staging" to the rake task in `crontab -e` also fixes the problem but I'm looking for a way to not have to declare that in every cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Υou can set the environment variables in crontab (not in Arch or RedHat though...)

try setting your crontab as follows

```
#crontab 

RAILS_ENV=staging

0 17 * * * cd /u/apps/my_app/current && /usr/local/bin/rake my_task
```